# Resizing more than one svg graph on the same web page

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, resize

I have written functions using d3.js to create SVG graphs.The graphs get resized when the window is resized. The (simplified) software pattern is like this:

```
function drawGraph(DIV, data){
// Draw the initial graph, which fills the supplied DIV

    function resize {
    // Read the new width and height of the SVG, redraw the graph
    }

    d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
    resize();
}
```

An excellent example of this pattern can for example be seen here:
https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/

This is my problem: I call the routine twice and create two SVG graphs on the same web page. When the window is resized, ONLY the last SVG drawn gets resized. How can I keep the first one "alive", so it will listen to the resize event?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on):

> If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the
>   selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new
>   listener is added. To register multiple listeners for the same event
>   type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as
>   "click.foo" and "click.bar". To remove a listener, pass null as the
>   listener. To remove all listeners for a particular event type, pass
>   null as the listener, and .type as the type, e.g. selection.on(".foo",
>   null).

So assuming DIV is a string identifier:

```
d3.select(window).on('resize.'+DIV, resize);
```

Comment: Thank you for you prompt answer, Mark. I found a (simple) solution myself. When I use `window.addEventListener("resize", resize)` in place of `d3.select(window).on('resize', resize)` both graphs scale properly.